# What does 前かmean?

Tags: translation, particles, interpretation

> 痛恨のミス。本来なら家を出る**前か**ホームルーム前に回しておくのだが、今朝は眠過ぎてそこまで頭が回っていなかったのだ。

It's from a light novel 時々ボソッとロシア語でデレる隣のアーリャさん1

The first question is: what does 前+か mean here?

The second one is:

> **家を出る**前か**ホームルーム前に回し**ておく

なぜ家を出る前ホームルームという大きな教室に回すと書いてあるの？家を出る前に人は家にいるのではないでしょうか？学校のような場所にしかないホームルームに回すはずがないと思う。

**この句はどう理解すればいいでしょうか？**(英語が苦手なので日本語で質問したのです)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What does 前+か mean here?

In this case, "か" means "or".

### Examples

- **黒 か 白** = black or white
- **はい か いいえ** = yes or no
- **家を出る前 か ホームルーム前** = before leaving house or before ホームルーム starts

---

## この句はどう理解すればいいでしょうか？

*Assuming "回す" means "無料ガチャを回す"...*

### First, you must understand:

- 前
- 回す
- 無料ガチャ
- ホームルーム

I recommend you research proper meanings and details on your own, but here's some brief explanation:

### 前 = before

- In this case "before" as in "before 12:00"
- 家を出る前 = before leaving the house
- ホームルーム前 = before ホームルーム starts

### 回す = the act of redeeming a 無料ガチャ

- Similar to spinning (回す) the slot machine in Las Vegas
- Or turning (回す) the capsule toy machine handle
- Although you're technically tapping on the screen

### 無料ガチャ = free attempt to redeem a random item

- It's like Reddit's free coins
- Users are often allowed freebies (for example one freebie a day)
- In your story, the free attempt expires noon

### ホームルーム

It's the first thing you do in school, like a daily morning meeting

---

## Conclusion

> 本来なら家を出る前かホームルーム前に回しておくのだが、今朝は眠過ぎてそこまで頭が回っていなかったのだ。

I will add several words to help clarify the situation:

> 本来なら、「家を出る前の時間」か「ホームルームがはじまる前の時間」に、無料ガチャを回しておくのだが、今朝は眠過ぎて、そこまで頭が回っていなかったのだ。

### The situation in English:

The character wanted to redeem a free item. The freebie expires noon. So, the character should have done that before leaving the house, or before the ホームルーム started. But the character was too sleepy, and forgot to do that. Oh no!